# Update Mouse Location When Scrolling With jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I was wondering about a solution for updating the mouse location after scrolling down the page.

In the attached codepen the div will stay at the last mouse location before scrolling until the mouse is moved again.

https://codepen.io/tylerrowens/pen/pojKLqY

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) we need to use **layerX** and **layerY** options

2) The position should be updated with the scroll event also.

```js
$("#scroll").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#hover").css({left:e.originalEvent.layerX, top:e.originalEvent.layerY});
});

$("#scroll").mousewheel(function(e){
    $("#hover").css({left:e.originalEvent.layerX, top:e.originalEvent.layerY});
});
```

```css
#hover{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:30px;
    margin: 30px;
}

#scroll{
    height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<div id="scroll">

</div>

<div id="hover">
    hover
</div>
```

Comment: OP is asking about jQuery.